# Dimension formula

Tags: commutative-algebra, krull-dimension

I know that for prime ideals $\text{ht}(P)+\dim(A/P)\leq \dim A$. I know that the result holds for any ideal $I$. Any hint on how to show this? I tried taking a minimal prime of $I$, and trying to estimate, but didn't get too far, since I don't know much on the structure of $\mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Take a maximal chain of primes contained in I and concatenate it with a chain of primes containing I, coming from a maximal chain of primes in A/I.

Comment: How would I use the definition using that the height of $I$ is the inf of the height of minimal overprimes of $I$?

Comment: Isn't obvious that $\dim A/I=\sup\{\dim A/P: P\supseteq I\}$? Then choose a prime $P$ where the equality holds.